# html php send form doesn't send email

Tags: php, html, forms

My form doesn't generate an E-Mail it just redirects me to a blank page.
i have my .php form in a folder named php on my server

thank you for your help.

here is my html code

```
      <form id="form" method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">
      <fieldset>
        <label><strong>Name:</strong>
          <input type="text" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Email:</strong>
          <input type="text" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Phone:</strong>
          <input type="text" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Message:</strong>
          <textarea></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="btns"><a href="#"  class="link">Clear</a><a href="php/send_form_email.php" class="link">Send</a></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

here is the php code i'm using:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "#@#.com";

$email_subject = "havok security contact form";





  function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there was an error found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

 }



 // validation expected data exists

 if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['message']; // required



  $error_message = "";

  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

   $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

   $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

  died($error_message);

  }

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



  function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





   // create email headers

   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

  ?>



   <!-- include your own success html here -->



   Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



   <?php

   }

    ?>
```

Comment: Is `php/send_form_email.php.php` the exact path to the php file relative to the form html file? The file does have two .php in it, correct?

Comment: yes i have an ubuntu server using webmin in my www folder i have my php folder php/send_form_email.php is the exact path to my php form.
sorry i should have mentioned that in the question post

Comment: oh i see now i duplicated .php.php on the extension. i feel like an idiot now. imma fix it and test it and see what happens
EDIT: i fixed the double extension and still no email so i guess i did something wrong in the script

Comment: the page and server is live if it will help anyone out in determining my issue the url is http://www.havoksecurity.com/contacts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input type under email needs to have a name attribute called "email".  Your PHP script is looking to see if $_POST["email"] is set, and it is not.  So, this should work:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">
      <fieldset>
        <label><strong>Name:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Email:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Phone:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
        </label>
        <label><strong>Message:</strong>
          <textarea name = "message"></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="btns"><a href="#"  class="link">Clear</a><a href="php/send_form_email.php" class="link">Send</a></div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: ok great does it matter if i leave no value for each input type?
im about to edit my html and give it a try

Comment: The value attribute is the default value of the textbox.  If you enter anything in value it will show up in the textbox.  Whatever you enter into the textboxes will overwrite the "value" attribute.  So, no it doesn't matter.

Comment: ok thats what i thought i wasn't sure. so i edited my html and still i got no email. do i have to set up some sort of mail server on my Ubuntu box to actually generate and send the email out to the email that is specified in the text box?

Comment: Yes, you will need an SMTP server running on the box and you will need to edit your php.ini file to connect to the SMTP server.

Comment: ok SyntaxLAMP you're the best what would i have to do to make SMTP connect to my php file? 

is this the part i would need to edit? and if so what to? sorry i know 0 php.

       // create email headers
 
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

Comment: also do i have to use SMTP coule i use postfix or dovecot ? which would be easier?

Comment: I do not believe that dovecot contains an SMTP server, I think dovecot is only an IMAP/POP server.  I think postfix is an SMTP server.

Comment: SMTP server is the mechanism that sends emails.  IMAP/POP and other mail daemons receive/process and present received emails to the user.

Comment: You have to edit the php.ini settings file and edit the SMTP connection information to match your setup.  Then, to send emails from PHP you use the mail() command. Here is a tutorial:  http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Local_Mail_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm

Comment: ok thank you. you helped me soo much. I would give you rep but i'm not high enough. looks like imma start learning php haha. thank you for real and have a good day SyntaxLAMP